# Passing session that has multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 files, maintransaction.php, computation.php, and computepayment.php

in maintransaction, it lists all the procedures and price which is in checkbox. once submitted, redirects to computation.php where it computes the checked procedures.

computation.php

```
foreach($ercharge as $charge) {
        $p = explode(",", $charge);
        $price[] = $p[0];            //stores the price of the $charge in $price array
        $procedure[] = $p[1];     // stores the procedure of the $charge in $procedure array
```

I added that to my 2nd file to get the procedure and the price. its in foreach so that when the user selects MULTIPLE values, it will store it in an array. Cause thats the tricky part, when a user selects more than one in the checkbox.

i also added this to test that the mutliple selected procedures where passed

```
foreach ($procedure as $pro) {
$_SESSION['receipt'] = $pro;
echo $_SESSION['receipt'];
}
```

it works fine. all the procedures checked where printed out.

after clicking another button, redirects to computepayment.php, where you enter the amount to be paid. 
i added this to the file:

```
print_r($_SESSION['receipt']);
```

it only shows ONE value. not ALL the values checked. i copied the foreach format from computation.php, as i wouldve guessed, it wouldnt work cause it doesnt recognize the variable $procedure.

How can i output the same values that were from the 2nd file, into the third file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the session values in $_SESSION['receipt']. The way you did it, you just overrode at every iteration, the code below adds it to the array.

```
$_SESSION['receipt'] = array();
foreach ($procedure as $pro) {
    $_SESSION['receipt'][] = $pro;
}
```